# Regex - Match RFC5424 "structured data" (Stop match with a space between "] [")

Tags: regex, syslog

Here's what I tried: this seems 'closest' `\[\S[a-zA-Z0-9]+@[0-8]+((\s[a-zA-Z]+=".+")+[\]]+)+`

```
\[[a-zA-Z0-9]+@[0-8]+(\s[a-zA-Z]+=".+"(?=\])+)+
\[\S[a-zA-Z0-9]+@[0-8]+(\s[a-zA-Z]+=".+"(?=\])+)+
\[[^ ][a-zA-Z0-9]+@[0-8]+(\s[a-zA-Z]+=".+"(?=\])+)+
\[\S[a-zA-Z0-9]+@[0-8]+((\s[a-zA-Z]+=".+")+\S[\]]+)+
\[\S[a-zA-Z0-9]+@[0-8]+((\s[a-zA-Z]+=".+")+[\]]+)\S
(\[\S[a-zA-Z0-9]+@[0-8]+((\s[a-zA-Z]+=".+")+[\]]+)+\S)
```

But I kep matching `] ...` (space after bracket)
basically I should only match lines that meet
`[*@# something="value" ...]`
where something="value" can repeat. If there's another bracket on the same line, it should all match as one line, without spaces between brackets...
`[*@# something="val"][*@# something="val"]`

Here's the data I'm testing against:

```
invalid (do not match)
; should not match, space between ][
[Example1SDID@32473 iut="3" eventSource="Application" eventID="1011"] [example1gPriority@32473 class="high"]
; should not match, space after [ and/or ]
[ Example2aSDID@32473 iut="3" eventSource="Application" eventID="1011"][example2fPriority@32473 class="high"]
[Example2bSDID@32473 iut="3" eventSource="Application" eventID="1011"][ example2ePriority@32473 class="high"]
[Example2cSDID@32473 iut="3" eventSource="Application" eventID="1011" ][ example2dPriority@32473 class="high"]

[Example3SDID@32473 iut="3" eventSource="Application" eventID="1011"][example2Priority@32473 nothing]
[Example2SDID@32473 iut="3" eventSource="Application" eventID="1011"][example2Priority@32473 class="high" ]
[Example2SDID@32473 iut="3" eventSource="Application" eventID="1011"][example2Priority@32473 class="high" ]
[this@that]
[example2Priority@32473 nothing]
[example4SDID@32473 iut="3" eventSource="Application" eventID="1011" ]

[asldkf;asd;fjas;dfj;asdjkf;asjkdffkdk]
[asdfas;dfjasdf
dfdss]

valid (match)
[example4SDID@32473 iut="3" eventSource="Application" eventID="1011"]
[example5SDID@32473 iut="3"]
[example6SDID@32473 iut="3" eventSource="Application" eventID="1011"][example6Priority@32473 class="high"]
```

Comment: Change `.+` to `.+?` so it's not greedy. Or `[^"]+`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want partial matches, you can anchor the pattern with `^` and `$`

To prevent spaces between the closing and opening square brackets `] [` you can repeat the whole part `[  ]` one or more times so that there can not be spaces in between.

Then use a negated character class to match from `"..."`

Note that `\s` can also match newlines.

```
^(?:\[[a-z0-9]+@[0-8]+(?:\s[a-zA-Z]+="[^"]*")+])+$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group (for `[...]`)

  - `\[` Match `[`
  - `[a-z0-9]+@[0-8]+` Match 1+ chars a-z0-9 `@` 1+ digits 0-8
  - `(?:` Non capture group (for  `..=".."`)

    - `\s[a-zA-Z]+="[^"]*"` Match a whitespace char, 1+ chars a-zA-Z `=` and then `"..."`
  - `)+` Close the non capture group and repeat it 1+ times
  - `]` Match literally
- `)+` Close the outer non capture group, and repeat it 1+ times
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CKrtGV/1)

If you want to allow escaped double quotes in between the double quotes:

```
^(?:\[[a-z0-9]+@[0-8]+(?:\s[a-zA-Z]+="(?:[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)")+])+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kcpV2u/1)